# How to generate Code when not found any code

Tags: c#

I have a table that name is `Sell` . I have `CustomeCode` in that table and I need to save uniqe code in that field .
I have already generated a lot of data in `Customecode` Table and when I want to add new records I read a code from that table (`customeCode`) .

I have these fields in CustyomeTable :`Id, Code,IsUsed`
sometimes there is no  Code and My application throw an exception .

How can I handle this ?

my code is like :

```
var result =_db.CusomeCode.firstOrDefault(row=>row.isUsed!=true);
if(result!=null) return result.Code;
if(result==null) throw new exception();
```

Comment: From the code you itself are throwing exception via `throw new exception` line. what exactly do you want is still unclear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How are you reading the variable "code" and what if the result retrieved is null ?

Comment: @rene updated .

Comment: @KaranDesai in new Code but there is no code and I should generate new code and check it to sure it hasn't used befor

Comment: When your `result` is null generate the unique code instead of throwing exception. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing an error,

```
if(code==null) throw new exception();
```

You could simply add a new code to the table

```
var code = new CustomCode();
code.isUsed = true;
code.Code = GenerateNewCode();
while(_db.CustomCode.Any(a => a.Code == code.Code)){
    code.Code = GenerateNewCode();
}
_db.CustomCode.add(code);
_db.SaveChanges();
return code.Code;
```

edit: I assume you have a function (GenerateNewCode()) somewhere to generate codes, and that the CusomeCode table has auto Id for the Id field.

edit#2: added while loop to check if code exists in table.

Comment: in this case I should check new code is it exict, beacuse mybye it used before

Comment: Added while loop to check for that.